# How to transpose and merge same column names after transposing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that has column names in the index and values in a column next to it like so:

```
      column
col1    a
col2    b
col3    c
col1    d
col2    e
col3    f
```

How do I flip and merge the index into columns like so?

```
col1     col2    col3
a         b        c 
d         e        f
```

I tried:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df).transpose()
```

new_df looks like this:

```
col1    col2     col3     col1   col2  col3
a        b         c        d     e      f
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and parameter `append=True` for `MultiIndex` and then reshape by first level by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True)['column'].unstack(0)
print (df)
    col1 col2 col3
0      a    b    c
1      d    e    f
```

Answer (score 2):

If they are symmetric as your example, can use just `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape([-1,3]), columns=df.index[:3])


    col1    col2    col3
0   a       b       c
1   d       e       f
```

Answer (score 1):

You can populate a dictionary first

```
d = {}
for k, v in df.column.items():
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

pd.DataFrame(d)

  col1 col2 col3
0    a    b    c
1    d    e    f
```